# Which Datatype should we use to store rupees and paisa?

Tags: postgresql

I am building an E-commerce platform and, while creating an invoice and saving to data base, it is not accurate; there is difference of 3-4 rupees in the final amount.

Which Datatype should we use to store rupees and paisa to avoid any inaccuracy?

Comment: What calculations are you using and where comes the difference from? You should include more details.

Answer (score 2):

It is always suggested to use **Decimal** datatype for storing monetary values. In PostgreSQL, **Numeric** datatype is equivalent to Decimal and hence it can be used.

Consider below given example for better understanding:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    price NUMERIC (5, 2)     // the second parameter is the precision for decimal values
);

INSERT INTO products (name, price) VALUES
    ('Phone', 100.21), 
    ('Tablet', 300.49);
```